# UINavigationItem BackBarButtonItem not replaced

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a curious issue with `backBarButtonItem`. I want to replace its title in the entire application for "Back" and replacing the back button works in most of `-viewDidLoad` event but in other views it's not working and show the name of the previous view. Has someone has the same problem?

P.S. The way to replace the `backBarButtonItem` is the standard one instantiating an `UIBarButtonItem` and setting it to `viewController.navigationIten.backBarButtonItem` property.

Comment: The Curious Case of Benjamin Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at last I've found the solution to this issue.

If you want that any backBarButtonItem of your application has the same title a good approach is to subclass UINavigationController and override `- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` to replace the back button.

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BackButtonLabel", "")
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                   target:nil 
                                                                   action:nil];
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
    _backButton = nil;
    [_backButton release];

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

By this way every back button in your application will have the same title.

I hope this will be helpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 16):

The `backBarButtonItem` does not set the back button that is shown in the current view, it sets the back button that *navigates to* the current view, i.e. the back button in the next view.

This makes sense because the back button's title is usually the title of the previous view controller.

If you want to set the left button in the navigation bar directly, use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: But why in some of the views it's working and not in another ones?

Comment: Frustrated that this is not documented at all. Thanks @omz

Comment: Lost on this long time，your answer verify my guess previous.

Answer (score 1):

when you push the view from your current view at that time after allocate your next viewcontroller object ,just put bellow line

```
YourViewController *objView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
          self.navigationItem.title=@"Back";
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objView animated:YES];
```

your Next View will Appear with Back Button....
:)

Comment: I tried it previously but it changes also the NavigationItem title before dissapeard and does not look so good...

Comment: in yourViewController in define also backBarButton m i right??

Comment: Not, it wasn't but at last I've solved it. See my own response below this.

Comment: oh ok ok dude but i get Back button title withBack with my above code ... but this is also right... :)

Comment: I know! Thanks for your help anyway :)